# Combine two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to combine these two arrays of objects together and get the output below.
`userid` property should be unique but not `name` or `role`

Input

```
const first = [
  { userid: 2, name: "Velen" },
  { userid: 56, name: "Illidan" },
  { userid: 23, name: "Muradin" },
  { userid: 12, name: "Sylvanas" },
  { userid: 44, name: "Cenarius" },
  { userid: 4, name: "Gul'Dan" },
];

const second = [
  { userid: 2, role: "Mage" },
  { userid: 4, role: "Worlock" },
  { userid: 56, role: "Demon Hunter" },
  { userid: 66, role: "Druid" },
  { userid: 87, role: "Shaman" },
  { userid: 12, role: "Hunter" },
];
```

Output

```
[
    { name: 'Velen',    role: 'Mage',       userid: 2 },
    { name: "Gul'Dan",  role: 'Worlock',    userid: 4 },
    { name: 'Sylvanas', role: 'Hunter',     userid: 12 },
    { name: 'Muradin',  role: null,         userid: 23 },
    { name: 'Cenarius', role: null,         userid: 44 },
    { name: 'Illidan',  role: 'Demon Hunter', userid: 56 },
    { name: null,       role: 'Druid',      userid: 66 },
    { name: null,       role: 'Shaman',     userid: 87 }
]
```

I tried this solution but it didn't work:

```
const solution = (first, second) => {
  first.sort((a, b) => a.userid - b.userid);
  second.sort((a, b) => a.userid - b.userid);
  first.map((item, idx) => {
    return {
      a: (item.role = second[idx].role),
      b: (item.userid = second[idx].userid),
    };
  });
  return first;
};
console.log(solution(first, second));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce with an object and take a default object with nullified values.

```js
const
    first = [{ userid: 2, name: "Velen" }, { userid: 56, name: "Illidan" }, { userid: 23, name: "Muradin" }, { userid: 12, name: "Sylvanas" }, { userid: 44, name: "Cenarius" }, { userid: 4, name: "Gul'Dan" }],
    second = [{ userid: 2, role: "Mage" }, { userid: 4, role: "Worlock" }, { userid: 56, role: "Demon Hunter" }, { userid: 66, role: "Druid" }, { userid: 87, role: "Shaman" }, { userid: 12, role: "Hunter" }],
    result = Object.values([...first, ...second].reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.assign(r[o.userid] ??= { name: null, role: null }, o);
        return r;
    }, {}));
    console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a `reduce` function as follow:

```
// adding empty model to make sure we'll get all keys
const emptyObj = {role: null, name: null}
const emptyObj = {role: null, name: null}
const userids = [...new Set([...first, ...second].map(item => item.userid))]

const output = userids.reduce((acc, cur) => {

  return [...acc, {...emptyObj, ...cur, ...(second.find(({userid}) => userid === cur ) ?? {}), ...(first.find(({userid}) => userid === cur ) ?? {})}]
}, [])
```

Comment: I like the idea of reduce method but when I ran your code is giving different output from the one I posted.

Comment: You are speaking about the missing null values? I edited my answer to meet your need!

Comment: it was not just about missing null, your solution is only giving the userid property of the first array, it not combining the second array userid, 
I am only getting 6 objects as output which they supposed to be 8 objects.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. Reworked it based on an array of userids so nothing is missing!

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of situation it's great to use Maps/Dictionary/ (key/value) data structure in general. Where the key is the userid in this situation and the value are the attributes you want to store.

```js
const first = [
  { userid: 2, name: "Velen" },
  { userid: 56, name: "Illidan" },
  { userid: 23, name: "Muradin" },
  { userid: 12, name: "Sylvanas" },
  { userid: 44, name: "Cenarius" },
  { userid: 4, name: "Gul'Dan" },
];

const second = [
  { userid: 2, role: "Mage" },
  { userid: 4, role: "Worlock" },
  { userid: 56, role: "Demon Hunter" },
  { userid: 66, role: "Druid" },
  { userid: 87, role: "Shaman" },
  { userid: 12, role: "Hunter" },
];

const solution = (first, second) => {
  const combined = new Map();
  for (const item of first) {
    combined.set(item.userid, { ...item, role: null });
  }
  for (const item of second) {
    if (combined.has(item.userid)) {
      combined.get(item.userid).role = item.role;
    } else {
      combined.set(item.userid, { ...item, name: null });
    }
  }
  return Array.from(combined.values()).sort((a, b) => a.userid - b.userid);
};

console.log(solution(first, second));
```

In the end we sort using userid like what you tried to do.
Without the sort the time complexity of the solution is `O(n)`. With the sort it's `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: that makes sense, 
when you run your solution
look at the last two objects, role came before name unlike the objects before that

Comment: @Rio0o.dev JavaScript does not guarantee the order of properties in an object.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could think of using reduce, had to use two of them to achieve the wanted result. Assuming the first array always contains `userid` and `name` while the second array always contains `userid` and `role`.

```js
const first = [
  { userid: 2, name: "Velen" },
  { userid: 56, name: "Illidan" },
  { userid: 23, name: "Muradin" },
  { userid: 12, name: "Sylvanas" },
  { userid: 44, name: "Cenarius" },
  { userid: 4, name: "Gul'Dan" },
];

const second = [
  { userid: 2, role: "Mage" },
  { userid: 4, role: "Worlock" },
  { userid: 56, role: "Demon Hunter" },
  { userid: 66, role: "Druid" },
  { userid: 87, role: "Shaman" },
  { userid: 12, role: "Hunter" },
];

const solution = (first, second) => {
    const firstReduce = first.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        const roleElem = second.find(elem => elem.userid === curr.userid);
        if (roleElem) {
           return [...acc, {...curr, role: roleElem.role}];
        }
        return [...acc, {...curr, role: null}];
    }, []);
    
    const secondReduce = second.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const elem = firstReduce.find(elem => elem.userid === curr.userid);
      if (!elem) {
         return [...acc, {...curr, name: null}];
      }
      return acc;
    }, firstReduce);
    
    return secondReduce;
}

console.log(solution(first, second));
```